# How could the Jews have been sure the Golden Calf wasn't actually G-d?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, avodah-zarah

This probably sounds like a ridiculous question, but in all seriousness, many Jews lost their lives in the aftermath of the worship of the Golden Calf (Shemos 32:27-28). While I understand only 40 days or so before they began to worship the Calf, G-d had spoken to them and instructed them not to worship any other G-d. How could they be sure that their mistaken belief in some sort of incarnated or intermediary, or a physical form of G-d was in fact false, to the extent that they deserved death?

Comment: They never believ that the Golden Calf is G_d. See Ramban ki tisa. Welcome to mi yodeya

Comment: @kouty updated.

Comment: Dibrah #1: I, G-d, have taken you out of Egypt. Aharon said at Cheit HaEgel: This is your god, Israel, who took you out of Egypt.

Comment: Thou shalt not make unto thee any graven image

Comment: @kouty, source that the Ramban speaks for all commentators/Judaism as a whole?

Comment: @ I have no source. But the bet Halevi says the same. but I have no source for others

Comment: @m.r. It's my understanding that the Egel was actually an animate form beast (Midrash Rabba). While what you're saying could be correct, that they were killed for their involvement in the making of the calf, I think it also might be that it was the worship itself that was the issue, mostly because when Moses returns he gives them a chance to join up with him.

Comment: Why do think any Avoda Zara in those days was provably not god? I would assume the commandment not to worship any other god included and was probably specifically aimed at a god that a person would think is real and therefore worship. Do you think Hashem would tell them not to do something they wouldn't have done?

Comment: @user6591 Well that's kind of my question. How would the average Israelite know that the Eigel wasn't _actually_ HaShem? Perhaps HaShem _could_ incarnate, take physical form, etc.

Comment: Than He might be Baal Pe'or or Ra. So how do we ever know? That's my point. Why focus on the Egel?

Answer (score 5):

They knew it wasn't God from the start:

> וַיַּרְא הָעָם, כִּי-בֹשֵׁשׁ מֹשֶׁה לָרֶדֶת מִן-הָהָר; וַיִּקָּהֵל הָעָם עַל-אַהֲרֹן, וַיֹּאמְרוּ אֵלָיו קוּם עֲשֵׂה-לָנוּ אֱלֹהִים אֲשֶׁר יֵלְכוּ לְפָנֵינוּ--כִּי-זֶה מֹשֶׁה הָאִישׁ אֲשֶׁר הֶעֱלָנוּ מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם, לֹא יָדַעְנוּ מֶה-הָיָה לוֹ.
>
> And when the people saw that Moses delayed to come down from the mount, the people gathered themselves together unto Aaron, and said unto him: 'Up, make us a god who shall go before us; for as for this Moses, the man that brought us up out of the land of Egypt, we know not what is become of him.' ([Shemot 32:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0232.htm#1))

They weren't fooled by some "god" that was presented to them; they *made* it, knowing what they were doing.  They said to Aharon "we don't know what's up with that other one; make us a new god".

They were told 40 days earlier not to make idols or chase after other gods.  They did it anyway.  They might have been frightened, but the *p'shat* is that they were not unaware -- they were, indeed, quite intentional in their actions.

Comment: This assumes that making an idol with one's own hands is proof against it's powers. All of us and Dovid Hamelech agree. But apparently idol worshippers did not and do not see this as proof against their beliefs.

Comment: @user6591 oh, along the lines of making a vessel for the "god" to dwell in, so they made the idols but thought their gods would then inhabit them?  Perhaps I took the question too literally.

Comment: I guess. I don't know the real logic. There is that Medrash where Avraham smashed all the idols etc and in the end terech said an idol can't smash anything. He was aware of their physical constraints and he would still pray to and worship them. Were they channeling agents? Then what did Avraham prove? It's confusing to me.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm pretty sure "the people" mentioned in that verse are referring to the "erev rav" who undoubtedly are guilty as the instigators. My question is more concerned with the average Israelite that "went along with it."

Comment: @Fei23 that's possible, but the text doesn't say.  It also raises the question of why Aharon would listen to the demands of the erev rav if they acted alone.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think it was in order to save his own life. From what I remember, he was under the assumption that no one (perhaps no non-erev rav Israelite) was actually going to commit idol worship and that one not need give over their life just to 'make an image.'

Comment: I read that Avoda Zara seems very stupid to us now because of the prayers to eliminate it. And when the Moshiach comes ,all aveirot will look stupid to us.